# unused node detected: ccnet 1.6.7981.1

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

i try to configure **ccnet** using [this link](http://www.zorched.net/2009/01/30/dry-your-cruisecontrolnet-configuration/) tag as below

ccnet.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder" xmlns="http://thoughtworks.org/ccnet/1/6">
    <!--# Genel Tanimlamalar -->
    <cb:include href="definitions.config" xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder"/>
    <!--# Project1.config -->
    <cb:include href="C:\buildBase\builds\Project1\Project1.config" xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder"/>
</cruisecontrol>
```

definitions.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cb:config-template xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">

    <cb:define name= "project-definition-block">
        <workingDirectory>C:\builBase\builds\$(project)</workingDirectory>
        <artifactDirectory>C:\builBase\builds\$(project)\artifact</artifactDirectory>
        <category>$(category)</category>
        <webURL>http://ccnet.gp.tr:81/server/ViewLatestBuildReport.aspx</webURL>
        <modificationDelaySeconds>2</modificationDelaySeconds>
        <maxSourceControlRetries>5</maxSourceControlRetries>
        <initialState>Started</initialState>
        <startupMode>UseInitialState</startupMode>

        <description>$(description)</description>
        <askForForceBuildReason>Required</askForForceBuildReason>
        <sourceControlErrorHandling>ReportOnRetryAmount</sourceControlErrorHandling>
        <state type="state" directory="C:\builBase\builds\$(project)\state" />

    </cb:define>
 .
 .
 .
 .      

    <cb:define name="labeller-block">
        <labeller type="assemblyVersionLabeller">
            <major>0</major>
            <minor>1</minor>
            <incrementOnFailure>false</incrementOnFailure>
        </labeller>
    </cb:define>

</cb:config-template>
```

Project1.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cb:config-template xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">

<cb:scope xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder"
         svn-folder="xxxxx" 
         project="XYZ"
         build-args="/p:Configuration=Debug"
         build-targets="Clean;Test"
         triggerInSeconds = "60"
         category = "X"
         description= "XYZ Programi">

    <project name ="$(project)" queue="Q1" queuePriority="1">

        <cb:project-definition-block/>

        <cb:svn-block/>

        <cb:labeller-block/>

        <cb:loggers-block/>

        <tasks>
            <cb:msbuild-35-block/>
        </tasks>

        <publishers>

            <cb:merge-block/>

            <cb:stats-block/>

            <cb:loggers-block/>
        </publishers>

    </project>
</cb:scope>
```

i am getting

ccnet.log

```
2011-07-29 15:24:46,109 [1:DEBUG] The trace level is currently set to debug.  This will cause CCNet to log at the most verbose level, which is useful for setting up or debugging the server.  Once your server is running smoothly, we recommend changing this setting in C:\tools\ci\ccent\server\ccnet.exe.Config to a lower level.
2011-07-29 15:24:46,140 [1:WARN] ! ! Tracing is enabled ! !It allows you to sent the developpers of CCNet very detailed information of the program flow. This setting should only be enabled if you want to report a bug with the extra information. When bug reporting is done, it is advised to set the trace setting off. Adjust the setting in C:\tools\ci\ccent\server\ccnet.exe.Config
2011-07-29 15:24:46,140 [1:DEBUG] [FileChangedWatcher] Add config file 'ccnet.config' to file change watcher collection.
2011-07-29 15:24:46,156 [CCNet Server:INFO] Reading configuration file "C:\tools\ci\ccent\server\ccnet.config"
2011-07-29 15:24:46,515 [CCNet Server:DEBUG] [FileChangedWatcher] Add config file 'C:\tools\ci\ccent\server\ccnet.config' to file change watcher collection.
2011-07-29 15:24:46,515 [CCNet Server:DEBUG] [FileChangedWatcher] Add config file 'C:\tools\ci\ccent\server\definitions.config' to file change watcher collection.
2011-07-29 15:24:46,515 [CCNet Server:DEBUG] [FileChangedWatcher] Add config file 'C:\buildBase\builds\Project1\Project1.config' to file change watcher collection.
2011-07-29 15:24:46,734 [CCNet Server:DEBUG] MergeFilesTask: Add 'C:\builBase\builds\Project1\reports\*.Test.xml' to 'Merge' file list.
2011-07-29 15:24:46,734 [CCNet Server:DEBUG] MergeFilesTask: Add 'C:\builBase\builds\Project1\reports\*.CoverageMerge.xml' to 'Merge' file list.
2011-07-29 15:24:46,734 [CCNet Server:DEBUG] MergeFilesTask: Add 'C:\builBase\builds\Project1\reports\*.CoverageSummary.xml' to 'Merge' file list.
2011-07-29 15:24:46,734 [CCNet Server:DEBUG] MergeFilesTask: Add 'C:\builBase\builds\Project1\reports\*.FxCop.xml' to 'Merge' file list.
2011-07-29 15:24:47,046 [CCNet Server:ERROR] Exception: Unused node detected: xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder"
----------
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.ConfigurationException: Unused node detected: xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder"
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.NetReflectorConfigurationReader.DefaultErrorProcesser.ProcessError(String message)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.NetReflectorConfigurationReader.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Read>b__0(InvalidNodeEventArgs args)
   at Exortech.NetReflector.InvalidNodeEventHandler.Invoke(InvalidNodeEventArgs args)
   at Exortech.NetReflector.NetReflectorTypeTable.OnInvalidNode(InvalidNodeEventArgs args)
   at Exortech.NetReflector.XmlTypeSerialiser.HandleUnusedNode(NetReflectorTypeTable table, XmlNode orphan)
   at Exortech.NetReflector.XmlTypeSerialiser.ReadMembers(XmlNode node, Object instance, NetReflectorTypeTable table)
   at Exortech.NetReflector.XmlTypeSerialiser.Read(XmlNode node, NetReflectorTypeTable table)
   at Exortech.NetReflector.NetReflectorReader.Read(XmlNode node)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.NetReflectorConfigurationReader.Read(XmlDocument document, IConfigurationErrorProcesser errorProcesser)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.DefaultConfigurationFileLoader.Load(FileInfo configFile)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.FileConfigurationService.Load()
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.FileWatcherConfigurationService.Load()
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.CachingConfigurationService.Load()
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseServer..ctor(IConfigurationService configurationService, IProjectIntegratorListFactory projectIntegratorListFactory, IProjectSerializer projectSerializer, IProjectStateManager stateManager, IFileSystem fileSystem, IExecutionEnvironment executionEnvironment, List`1 extensionList)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseServerFactory.CreateLocal(String configFile)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseServerFactory.Create(Boolean remote, String configFile)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.ConsoleRunner.LaunchServer()
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Console.AppRunner.Run(String[] args, Boolean usesShadowCopying)
```

i almost tried everything, spent time for googling, what can be the problem? Which one is the node unused.. ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Unused-node-detected-Exceptions often point to a malformed configuration.

First guess: The publisher block in Project1.config is missing its closing tag. Perhaps this is the cause?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No,this tag closed actually,but file is long so when i trimm it,missed :) waiting for your 2nd guess.